# Trying to get a progress spinner to fade in using CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to get a spinner to fade in. I am using this progress spinner: [JQuery Progress Spinner](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/)

It allows one to specify a CSS class to add CSS effects, which I have called spinner.

My CSS for the spinner class is :

```
.spinner {
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

But it does not work. I am using this with Ajax, and if the response is < 1 sec then I do not want the progress spinner, so in this case it will not have faded in. Except it does, so I get the spinner appearing for about 50ms which is not ideal.

I guess there is something, rather trivial, that is incorrect with my CSS.

EDIT 1:

I am transitioning from transparent(white which is my background colour) to the spinner.

Comment: You're "transitioning" what is it transitioning from? You'll need to toggle a class on it or something that's opacity: 0; to opacity: 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is correct, you only lack logic to know when to hide the `.spinner`. You could use something like this:

```css
/* CSS */
.spinner {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
       -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
         -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
            transition: opacity 2s linear;
    border: 1px solid red;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.hidden {
    opacity: 0.0;
}
```

And add a call to hide the `.spinner`. This example hides it when button is clicked, you could use `ajax().done()` to work with your code.

```js
// JavaScript
$("#hide").click(function () {
    $("#foo").addClass("hidden");
});
```

I have set up an example on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hepm6/).

Comment: Thanks for this. Should I not be able to get the spinner just fading in over 2 seconds, when displayed. I never see this.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by fading in, it does fade in time span of 2 seconds. After some testing, I've noticed that this doesn't work in IE for some reason, even with the [old IE fixes](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/). Another fallback you could use is `$("selector").fadeOut(2000);`. With jQuery `.fadeOut` function, you don't need any css at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, basically I mean from white, which is the colour of the background, so I guess that is transparent to the colour of the image. If this was an animated gif, then the gif would get darker and darker from white.

Comment: This should work the same, be it an dom element (current example) or an image.

Answer (score 2):

Add an active class to spinner, when ajax completes. And add the following css.

```
spinner {
  opacity: 0;
 -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
 -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
 transition: opacity 2s linear;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.spinner.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there not a way to have one class and just delay the display of the image, over say 2secs

Answer (score 1):

You'll also have to toggle a class that is controlling the "opacity" css attribute.

[JSFiddle of how opacity and transitions work.](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/mqW96/2/)

```
.spinnerDummy{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background:blue;
    border-radius: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}

spinnerDummy.opacity{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You could also set a timeout function on your loading gif:

```
setTimeout(function() {
 $('.spinnerDummyFadeIn').addClass('opacity');
}, 1000 );
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/mqW96/7/)

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xenyph/8r6uZ/)

You could use an animation like in the above link.  Click Run to watch the animation again.

I created a custom animation, in this case `myfirst`, and then attached it to the class I wanted to display the animation on, `.fade`.

Define animation:

```
@keyframes myfirst {
from {opacity: 0}
to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Attach it and assign length of animation:

```
.fade{
    animation: myfirst 1s;
}
```

Put the keyframes part anywhere in your CSS and then attach the `.fade` class to your spinner.  The code in my jsfiddle is what you should be using for optimal compatibility.

[Animations on W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)