# Angularjs Showing Loading spinner

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

Here is my ajax request,

I wanted to show the loading spinner. I refered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular) but i am not clear in it.

I just wanted to show the spinner during the `$http.post` and hide after the post is done.

Something like `angular.element('#mydiv').show()` and `angular.element('#mydiv').hide()` inside the call. In which place shall  i give that to show the `#mydiv` during the post was in progress.

**Here is my call**

```
$scope.doVerify={email:'',password:''};
    $scope.doVerify = function () 
    {
     email = $scope.verify.useremail;
     password = $scope.verify.password;
     $scope.data.show = false; 
     $http.post('VerifyUser', { email: email, password: password}).then(function (results) 
     {
     $scope.data.show = true
     if(results.data=='success')
     {
     $location.path('registration');
     }
     else
     {
     $scope.data.msg = 'Incorrect Password'
     }
     });
    };
```

Where shall i put the `angular.element('#mydiv').show()` and `angular.element('#mydiv').hide()` to the loader ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.element('#mydiv').show()` needs to go before you make $http call and `angular.element('#mydiv').hide()` should go in success and error callbacks.

```
angular.element('#mydiv').show(); // show loading spinner
$http.post('VerifyUser', { email: email, password: password}).then(function (results) {
    angular.element('#mydiv').hide(); // hide loading spinner
});
```

Comment: Can i do something like $('#mydiv').fadeOut(100); i.e., To make `#mydiv` appear and disappear slowly.. ?

Comment: i believe yes, as long as you have jQuery in your app.

Comment: May i do that in angularjs itself ?

Comment: No. [angular is using jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) but `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` are not one of its methods.

Comment: is there anything there, so that i can do something like appear slowly ?

Comment: You can use `angular-animate` with `ng-show` and `ng-hide`. Or, `addClass` method with some css3 for animation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best solution to do this is to add the spinner in the HTML like so:

`<div ng-show="spinnerVisibility" class="spinner></div>`

and then control the `spinnerVisibility` variable in the controller before/after making a post. Example:

```
$scope.spinnerVisibility = true;
$http.post('VerifyUser', { email: email, password: password}).then(function (results) {
    $scope.spinnerVisibility = false;
});
```

Comment: thanks, may i make that div `spinner` to appear slowly like fadeout or something like that ?

Comment: Yeah sure - you can do that with CSS3. Simply append/remove a class that will do the fadeIn/fadeOut effect. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868844/trying-to-get-a-progress-spinner-to-fade-in-using-css

Answer (score 1):

Here How you can show the spinner in your code.
show or hide your img/icon whre the $scope.prograssing var sets.

```
$scope.doVerify={email:'',password:''};
        $scope.doVerify = function () 
        {
         email = $scope.verify.useremail;
         password = $scope.verify.password;
         $scope.data.show = false; 

    $scope.sendAjax = function() {
    $scope.prograssing = true; // show spinner here
    $http.post('VerifyUser', { email: email, password: password}).then(function (results) 
             {
             $scope.data.show = true
             if(results.data=='success')
             {
             $location.path('registration');
    $scope.prograssing = false;        // hide spinner when successful
             }
             else
             {
             $scope.data.msg = 'Incorrect Password';
    $scope.prograssing = false;        // hide spinner when unsuccessful
             }
             });
           };
$scope.sendAjax();
       };
```

Answer (score 1):

`angular.element('#mydiv').show()` needs to go inside the definition of your interceptor. Interceptors are pushed inside the config block of the angular module.  Exactly the way the it has been done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular).

`angular.element('#mydiv').hide()` needs to go inside the response of the $http service(inside the `'then'` block).

The example you are referring is doing it exactly the way it should.